# Is it safe to `reinterpret_cast` two unrelated vector of objects when those objects have the same binary representation?

Tags: c++, casting

I have newtypes around int, as well as classes that contains those newtype.

```cpp
class IndexA {
    int i;
};
class A {
    IndexA index;
};

// this mimic exactly the hierarchy of `A`
struct IndexB {
    int i;
};
struct B {
    IndexB index;
};
```

Given that `A` and `B` share the exact same binary layout, does the following code contains undefined behavior or is it safe?

```cpp
std::vector<A> vfoo {...};
std::vector<B> vbar {
    std::move(
        reinterpret_cast<std::vector<B>&>(vfoo)
    )
};
```

I would have liked to be able to do a zero copy move transformation from `std::vector<A>` to `std::vector<B>`. Is it possible?

In my code:

- `A` and `B` are really just a wrapper around `int`, so they have exactly the same binary representation.
- The struct `A` only contains a mix of `IndexA`, `std::optional<IndexA>`, `std::variant<IndexA, other types like IndexA>`, or `std::vector<IndexA or std::optional<IndexA>, …>`. I think that I can assume that they have the same representation.
- `B` is a strict copy of `A`, where every instances of `IndexA` are replaced by `IndexB`. The fields order is kept.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it safe to `reinterpret_cast` two unrelated vector of objects when those objects have the same binary representation?

No, it is not safe. The behaviour of the example program is undefined.

> I would have liked to be able to do a zero copy move transformation from `std::vector<A>` to `std::vector<B>`. Is it possible?

No, it is not possible.

---

Something that you can do and is somewhat close to what you're trying is to have a vector of union of those types:

```
union IndexAB {
    IndexA A;
    IndexB B;
};

std::vector<IndexAB> vfoo {...};
for (IndexAB& u : vfoo) {
    std::cout << u.A.i;
    u.B.i = 42;
}
```

Whether `A` or `B` union member were activated doesn't matter. We can access either member regardless.

Note that this doesn't apply to all unions in general, but only in this particular case of standard layout structs, and specifically the members within their common initial sequence.

Comment: oh my, an actually well defined use of unions, how rare!  I'll bet dollars to donuts that someone mimicing it manages to trigger UB however.

Comment: If you can make the assumption that you’re running on ItaniumABI, then it’s well-defined; works on most common architectures.

Comment: @lorro Could you quote the ABI spec for benefit of those who can rely on it?

Comment: @eerorika Note that I can’t quote a specific place inthe standard; had this problem in the past and had the code reviewed by an independent dev. Took some time to prove it, but yes, on ItaniumABI you can have a template<typename...> GenericAggregate; for AggregateTypes, even for non-recursively Aggregates, _as long as_ padding (and possibly any other attribute) is the same.

Comment: @lorro `std::vector<T>` is not an aggregate type though (in C++ standard sense).

Comment: @eerorika Only A and B need to be (and not even recursively - but I’m not aware of a specific name for that). However, it’s still architecture-dependent (i.e., by the standard still UB).

Answer (score 3):

The standard does not allow you to convert between pointers of unrelated types, regardless of their binary layout:

```
struct A{ int i; };
struct B{ int i; };

B b{};
A* pa = reinterpret_cast<A*>(&b);
pa->i = 42; // undefined behavior
```

Comment: Interestingly, `int* i = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&b); *i = 42;` is well defined.

Comment: NB. ItaniumABI - as well as most ABIs I have encountered so far - define this as expected.

Comment: @lorro yes, it's likely to work as expected everywhere. It may fail due to some aggressive optimizations. UB is a slippery slope.